# Unknown type name 'namespace' in Xcode, other solutions do not work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

I'm running OS 10.11, and my Xcode version is 7.2.

All of the sudden my project fails to compile in Xcode. Xcode seems to be confused about the file type -- I'm getting errors that indicate my code is being compiled as C++ even tho all the files in my project are labeled as type Objective-C code. Here are some of the errors that occur in deeply-nested system header files:

`Unknown type name 'namespace' 'utility' file not found (from #include_next <utility>)`

I've verified that all the files are listed as Objective-C. I've even tried changing them to Objective-C++, by 'Identity and Type', and by also changing the extensions to .mm, but this introduces an even bigger set of mysterious compile errors deep in system-level header files, such as:

`Use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'? No member named 'memchr' in the global namespace`

I've tried reinstalling Xcode a couple times. Any suggestions?

Further mystifying is that I have a different Mac with the same version of OS X, same version of Xcode, and with the exact same code (verified thru git), and it compiles fine.

Comment: Is `#include_next <utility>` a line of code in your program? Did you recently add any new libraries or frameworks? Did you add any include statements to your prefix header?

Comment: I do not include it -- #include_next <utility> occurs in a deeply-nested system header file

Comment: I removed all libraries and frameworks from the project, but it had no effect.

Comment: What is the header that you include that causes this nested include?

Comment: @uliwitness, it's this:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

this #import also causes it:
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

Comment: Did you perhaps add compiler flags to the files in the Target's settings > Build Phases > Compile Sources that cause the files to behave that way ? Or do you have a `#define __cplusplus 1` or something like that in the precompiled header, or a `-D__cplusplus` compiler option in the CFLAGS of your target's Build Settings? Something that might have the headers thinking they were running under a C++ compiler when they weren't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new project, copied all the files and configuration to the new project, and the issue resolved itself.